# How can I eliminate borders when setting width to 100%?

Tags: html, css

I might be doing something really stupid and obvious wrong, but this is my first site so I'm not certain.

My problem is that I'm setting the header's width to be 100% but it is still leaving a border on either side. I've been going through the code at Codeacademy.com, but on their example they use something called, "bootstrap.css" and I wanted to do all the code myself to help me learn.

[HTML](http://pastebin.com/Q6VZnp9z)(sorry for the formatting, pasted from VIM and it all messed up =/)

[CSS](http://pastebin.com/QDg2Zc2g)

Edit:

Ok, I'm apparently not very good at using the search function (sorry!).

The answer is that 'body' has an inherent margin, setting the body style to include 'margin: 0;' removes this problem.

I.e.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel - can you post all of your code directly into the question?  That way it will be useful for the next person.

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting your `HTML` and `BODY` tags:

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; } // Do this near top of CSS
```

Comment: Thank you, I just realised this and was editing my post. I submitted the question and saw the answer pop up in the related posts. Sorry to waste you time, but thank you for the answer. Worked perfectly.

Comment: +1 Most browsers have a default stylesheet that adds padding and/or borders to both of those elements.